# Find the newest directory from a tuple inside a list with datetime

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, smb

On my network, a scheduled report creates a new directory (with random numbers) every time it runs and then places a CSV file inside it. I currently fetch files over SMB using **pysmbclient**, but I'm not sure how I can navigate to this reports latest directory with what the modules Glob returns (below).

How can I get to the last created directory, do I need to parse the *datetime.datetime*'s first somehow? Here's what I have:

```
import smbclient
import glob
import os

smb = smbclient.SambaClient(server=uk51, ip=10.10.10.10, share="share", 
      username="test", password="password", domain='office')

# recent = smb.glob(max(glob.iglob(\\*)), key=os.path.getctime)) # Latest directory
# smb.download(recent + "summary.csv", "/usr/reports/uk51.csv")) # Download latest dir's CSV


example = smb.glob('\\*')
print list(example) # Example of what Glob returns
```

> *#>* python script.py
>
> *#>*  [(u'1192957', u'D', 0, datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 23, 10, 29, 20)), (u'1193044', u'D', 0, datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 24, 10, 29, 22))]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those 4-tuples are how [pysmbclient](https://bitbucket.org/nosklo/pysmbclient/wiki/Home) returns data from `smb.glob()`. You don't need to parse the datetimes as they are already `datetime.datetime` objects which can be sorted as you would usually sort things. To get the final (3rd) value in each 4-tuple you can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
import operator as op

#example = [(u'1193044', u'D', 0, datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 24, 10, 29, 22)), 
#           (u'1192957', u'D', 0, datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 23, 10, 29, 20))]
example = list(smb.glob('\\*'))
example.sort(key=op.itemgetter(3),reverse=True)
most_recent_dir = example[0][0] # to get the most recent directory name
```

And then you would use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to build up the path to download:

```
import os

smb.download(os.path.join(most_recent_dir,"summary.csv"), "/usr/reports/uk51.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've never heard of the Operator library. It isn't working past the *example.sort* part, it goes to my Except statement. There is an (old) file in this directory, could that be causing an issue? It's readout is [...,(u'random.sv', u'A', 1125686, datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 2, 12, 45, 25))], it looks like it's also pulling datetime.

Comment: You're very welcome. What's the exception? That file shouldn't be causing any problems.

Comment: recent.sort(key=op.itemgetter(3),reverse=True)
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'sort'. 


I put in *list(example)* and it worked, but then it shows this error for most_recent_dir:      most_recent_dir = recent[0][0] # to get the recent dir
TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: How does it do if you remove this line: `recent = smb.glob(max(glob.iglob(\\*)), key=os.path.getctime))`?

Comment: You have two calls to `glob` functions. One of them isn't necessary.

Comment: That line was commented out for my own reference, the only glob I have is **recent = smb.glob('\\*')**

Comment: It looks like putting it into a variable as a list is not working (Turns into None), how should I pass it into the sort function? *recent = list(recent) # Cancels out the entire list*

Comment: `smb.glob()` "returns a list of tuples in the format: `[(filename, modes, size, date), ...]`" You should not be having to do `list()` for that.

Comment: Fixed that, thanks. I tried using *sorted*, but it throws the same error as *sort*:  (ttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'sort').

Comment: There is no place in the code you've provided where a generator is being created. So something else is going on.

Comment: It appears SMB.glob() is a generator, referencing it directly with a print statement returns a generator address. The only way I've found to see what it contains is to place it into a list, as shown in original post.

Comment: Ah you are right: https://bitbucket.org/nosklo/pysmbclient/src/e9efcae20d96b8b9ff52ce4ad412ec6e3897936e/smbclient.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#smbclient.py-268 I updated my example. The documentation for pysmbclient is in conflict with the source code.